# Making row value as column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I want to group the item and use the distinct value in company_name as my column name

// this is query in MYSQL

```sql
select tbl_addcolumn.quantity,tbl_addcolumn.unit,tbl_addcolumn.item,tbl_supplier.company_name,tbl_supplierprice.totalPrice,tbl_addcolumn.totalcost
FROM tbl_addcolumn
inner join tbl_supplierprice 
on tbl_addcolumn.id = tbl_supplierprice.itemName
inner join tbl_supplier
on tbl_supplierprice.fk_supplierId = tbl_supplier.id 
where tbl_supplier.pr_no = '2023-03-0001'  
ORDER BY `tbl_addcolumn`.`item` ASC
```

| quantity | unit | item | company_name | totalPrice | totalcost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | rim | A4 bond paper | EGB Trading | 300 | 750 |
| 5 | rim | A4 bond paper | Goodluck Trading | 500 | 750 |
| 50 | piece | black pen | EGB Trading | 300 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | black pen | Goodluck Trading | 200 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | blue pen | EGB Trading | 100 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | blue pen | Goodluck Trading | 200 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | red pen | EGB Trading | 100 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | red pen | Goodluck Trading | 200 | 250 |

My desire output is something like this:

| quantity | unit | item | EGB Trading | Goodluck Trading | totalcost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | rim | A4 bond paper | 300 | 500 | 750 |
| 50 | piece | black pen | 300 | 200 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | blue pen | 100 | 200 | 250 |
| 50 | piece | red pen | 100 | 200 | 250 |

Comment: There are lots of solutions posted for [mysql, pivot-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql+pivot-table) already. I recommend you check some of those out to see if you can gain an understanding of the techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this using a [CASE statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) .

*sample code*

```sql
    SELECT 
      date,
      MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'Item 1' THEN value END) AS 'Item 1',
      MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'Item 2' THEN value END) AS 'Item 2',
      MAX(CASE WHEN item = 'Item 3' THEN value END) AS 'Item 3'
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY date;
```

your updated query,

```
SELECT 
  tbl_addcolumn.quantity,  tbl_addcolumn.unit, tbl_addcolumn.item,  tbl_supplier.company_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_supplierprice.currency = 'EGB Trading' THEN tbl_supplierprice.totalPrice END) AS 'EGB Trading',
  MAX(CASE WHEN tbl_supplierprice.currency = 'Goodluck Trading' THEN tbl_supplierprice.totalPrice END) AS 'Goodluck Trading',
  tbl_addcolumn.totalcost
FROM tbl_addcolumn
INNER JOIN tbl_supplierprice   ON tbl_addcolumn.id = tbl_supplierprice.itemName
INNER JOIN tbl_supplier  ON tbl_supplierprice.fk_supplierId = tbl_supplier.id 
WHERE tbl_supplier.pr_no = '2023-03-0001'  
GROUP BY 
  tbl_addcolumn.quantity,
  tbl_addcolumn.unit,
  tbl_addcolumn.item,
  tbl_supplier.company_name,
  tbl_addcolumn.totalcost
ORDER BY 
  tbl_addcolumn.item ASC;
```

let me know the feedback if this works.